# Writing SQLite statement to retrieve all contacts information

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to write a sqlite statement to retrieve all the `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` column and the `_ID` from the `Contacts` Table (where all the phone contacts reside).

I hope it'll look something like the following:

Does it like `Select HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,  _ID from Contacts`

I actually require the java code where i could grab the records from the android phonebook (via the above SQLite statement) and save the results in an array or list

Comment: sorry but, what's the question? I think you already answered yourself

Comment: can u elaborate ....

Comment: I need the java code, where i could grab the records and save it in an array. I have updated my question

Comment: @Illep have you actually read the documentation?

Comment: Take a look at [ContactsProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Comment: Yes i went through it, but i actually want to access the records by the SQL query `Select * from .......` it self

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
           cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        // Do something with phones
        } 
        pCur.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to have the SQL query in the code. The query is `Select * from Contacts`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by the following method:-

```
    ArrayList<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

           String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           id.add(contact_id);


            }
        }
    }
              cursor.close();
```

and don't forgot to mention the read contacts permission in your menifest

Comment: Thanks, but where is the `Select` statement. I want to write the Select statement as well. like `select * from Contacts`

Comment: are you familiar with android,for writing above type of query you need database instance and here we have content resolver and i don't think we can run a rawquery on content resolver.Above is a method how we execute and retrieve data from queries in android

Comment: Can i use rawqueries on system tables such as the `Contacts` table ?

Comment: i don't think that is allowed in android.You can access system tables through content resolvers only and i afraid that it do not allow rawqueries